# Compile a single C# file using DNX/DNU

Tags: c#, dnx, dnu

Is it possible to compile a single C# file using the new .NET cross-platform toolchain (DNX/DNU) without first making a project.json file?

For example, with Mono you can do:

```
mcs Program.cs
```

The `mcs` command creates `Program.exe` if it finds a `Main` method otherwise it creates `Program.dll`.

I'm trying to build on Mac and Ubuntu using the open source Microsoft tools instead of Mono. I make a ton of tiny little programs for demonstration purposes and I don't want to have to create a project.json file every time.

Comment: Part of the problem would be that without a project.json file, there is way to include assembly references.  Given how the new DNX environment allows you to switch versions and runtime types, I doubt it can make assumptions, so it needs that bare minimum project.json I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that is possible. You would need project.json to build. 
If you try build `Program.cs` without project.json through dnu you would get "Unable to locate project.json"

```
PATH TO PROJECT>dnu build

Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Unable to locate project.json.
Total build time elapsed: 00:00:00.0133362
Total projects built: 1
```